# Problemas al llenar arreglos C++

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]en los ultimos dias me pasa seguido que al establecer un limite para llenar un arreglo en C++, el programa se sigue ejecutandose sin respetar este limite o simplemente crashea.
Aqui el codigo:

```
int main(){

    int lim, i; 
    float array[lim];

    cout<<"Ingrese el limite de elementos del arreglo: "; cin>>lim;

    for(i=0; i<lim; i++){

        cout <<"Ingrese un numero para el espacio ["<<i+1<<"]: ";
        cin>>array[i];


    }

    return 0;
}   //fin main
```

Answer (score 4):

Estás usando una característica de C++ que no se considera estándar, el "*Arreglo de Tamaño Variable*" (ATV).

---

Los ATV son formaciones<sup>1</sup> cuyo tamaño se ha definido mediante una variable en lugar de una constante, como es tu caso:

```
int lim, i; 
float array[lim];
```

`lim` es una variable, y usarla para definir `array` hace que éste sea un ATV. Los ATV no forman parte del estándar de C++ pero algunos compiladores les dan soporte mediante una extensión de compilador, [consulta estas preguntas para saber más del tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D).

Dado que no es C++ estándar, no te aconsejaré una solución como la de [Germán Martínez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233142/2742) si no que te aconsejaré que rehagas el código para no usar ATV:

#### Primera propuesta: Memoria dinámica.

No puedes crear formaciones<sup>1</sup> cuyo tamaño se defina mediante una variable a no ser que lo hagas en memoria dinámica (usando el operador `new`):

```
int main() {

    int lim;

    cout << "Ingrese el limite de elementos del arreglo: "; cin >> lim;

    float *array = new float[lim];

    for (int i = 0; i < lim; ++i) {
        cout << "Ingrese un numero para el espacio [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    delete[] array;

    return 0;
}
```

Al usar memoria dinámica (pedir memoria con `new`) debes liberarla manualmente con `delete` (en este caso, al ser memoria pedida para una formación, debes usar `delete[]`); ésto es engorroso, las tendencias de C++ moderno aconsejan...

#### Segunda propuesta: Memoria dinámica con puntero inteligente.

... usar un puntero inteligente que libera al programador de las preocupaciones de la gestión manual de memoria:

```
int main() {

    int lim;

    cout << "Ingrese el limite de elementos del arreglo: "; cin >> lim;

    auto array = make_unique<float[]>(lim);

    for (int i = 0; i < lim; ++i) {
        cout << "Ingrese un numero para el espacio [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Al usar el puntero inteligente `std::unique_ptr`, la gestión de memoria se hace automáticamente (no tienes que llamar a `delete[]` manualmente). Pero sigue siendo más de lo que tu código realmente necesita:

#### Tercera propuesta: Usa un contenedor de datos.

Tu código podría ser mucho más sencillo usando un contenedor de datos como la plantilla `std::vector`:

```
int main() {

    int lim;

    cout << "Ingrese el limite de elementos del arreglo: "; cin >> lim;

    vector<float> array(lim);

    for (int i = 0; i < lim; ++i) {
        cout << "Ingrese un numero para el espacio [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Uno de los [constructores de `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) acepta un número como tamaño inicial del contenedor, lo cuál se ajusta perfectamente a tus necesidades.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Se aconseja que el ámbito de las variables sea lo más pequeño posible; no es necesario que tu variable `i` para indexar el bucle `for` sea declarada de antemano, puede declararse y definirse en el bucle sin problemas.
- Favorece el pre-incremento frente al post-incremento (lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber por qué).

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás creando primero el array con **lim** con un valor indeterminado, y luego obtenes del usuario el valor **lim**.

O sea, primero tenes que ingresar el valor **lim**, y luego declarar el array, para crearlo con el valor ingresado y no un valor basura.

```
int main()
{
    int lim;

    cout<<"Ingrese el limite de elementos del arreglo: ";

    cin>>lim; // Primero: solicitar 'lim'

    float array[lim]; // Segundo: declarar el array

    for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
    {

        cout <<"Ingrese un numero para el espacio ["<<i+1<<"]: ";
        cin>>array[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te ha faltado comentar que, dado que `lim` es una variable, `array[lim]` es un *Variable Length Array* o *VLA*, característica **no soportada por el estándar de C++** o, dicho de otra forma, habría que usar memoria dinámica en vez de un array

Comment: @eferion Eso es cierto, pero con g++, si que se puede hacer, así que supuse que utilizaba g++ por como presentó el código en la pregunta.

Comment: Que g++ lo soporte actualmente no te da garantías de que lo soporte en el futuro. Conviene evitar (al menos en las respuestas) las características no soportadas por el estándar puesto que las respuestas no van a funcionar siempre (que le funcione al OP no implica que le vaya a funcionar a todo el que lea el hilo buscando respuestas a un problema similar). En caso de que no proceda dar una respuesta más universal, al menos hay que avisarlo en la respuesta