# ingresar a la posiciona de un arreglo y aumentar su valor

Tags: c++

Tengo un arreglo y quiero colocarme en una posición del arreglo y aumentar su valor. 
ejemplo.
tengo un arreglo de tamaño 5 = 0

```
[0][0][0][0][0]
```

y me piden aumentar "1" en las posiciones 1,3,2,3 y quedaría así el arreglo.

```
[0][1][1][2][0]
```

Código:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
   int n ;
   std::cin>>n;
   int arry[n];
   int arry1[n];
   for(int i = 0; i< n;i++){
       arry[i]= 0;
   }
   int m;
   std::cin>> m;
       for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){
       int x;
       std::cin >>x;

           for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++){

                   arry[x]=1+arry[x];
                             }
       }

   for(int i= 0 ; i < n ; i++){
       std::cout<<arry[i]<<" ";
   }
```

Comment: Disculpen es la primera ves que uso esta plataforma.

Comment: Y bien, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: en entender como funciona cada herramienta de la plataforma.
Pero lo iré descubriendo poco a poco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tengo un arreglo de tamaño 5 = 0 *[0][0][0][0][0]*

Bien, pues tienes esto:

```
//          v <--- Tamaño del arreglo
int arreglo[5]{}; // Al estar las llaves vacías, todos los elementos se inicializan a 0.
//  ^^^^^^^ <-- Nombre del arreglo
```

> aumentar "1" en las posiciones 1,3,2,3

Fácil:

```
++arreglo[1];
++arreglo[3];
++arreglo[2];
++arreglo[3];
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Estás usando una característica de C++ que no se considera estándar, el "*Arreglo de Tamaño Variable*" (ATV). Los ATV son formaciones<sup>1</sup> cuyo tamaño se ha definido mediante una variable en lugar de una constante, como es tu caso:

int n ;
   std::cin>>n;
   int arry[n];
   int arry1[n];
`n` es una variable, y usarla para definir `arry` y `arry1` hace que éstos sean ATVs. Los ATV no forman parte del estándar de C++ pero algunos compiladores les dan soporte mediante una extensión de compilador ([consulta estas preguntas para saber más del tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D)), mi consejo es que **NO los uses**, puedes encontrar alternativas a los ATV en [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233112/2742).

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Muchas gracias !!
tomare en cuenta tu recomendación

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes hacer es recorrer la lista de las posiciones, en tu ejemplo es (1,3,2,3) llamemosle lista

Luego por cada elemento de esa lista, accedes al arreglo que esta lleno con ceros, en tu ejemplo es [0][0][0][0][0] llamemosle array,

entonces al arreglo, en el indice de la posición que indica la lista en ese ciclo del bucle le sumas 1, es decir: 
array[lista[i]] = array[lista[i]] + 1

Pseudocudigo

```
for (i=0; i < lista.length ; i++)
  array[lista[i]] = array[lista[i]] + 1
```

Comment: Prefiero que entienda la solución y modifique su código y no que copie y pegue los cambios. Es la forma correcta de enseñar y también de aprender, todo lo que representa un mayor esfuerzo para lograr se graba mejor en la mente

Comment: si deseas puedes indicarle el código tu mismo, e incluso votar mi respuesta como poco útil, no veo la obligación de hacer lo que dices ni el porque de hacer una valoración negativa verbal como ¨cuadrado¨ hacia mi persona. :) . Respeto tu opinión, pero eso no cambia la mía, lo importante es aprender y no copiarse

Comment: Muchas gracias  !!

Comment: En cuanto a la respuesta que haz aceptado, ten en cuenta dos cosas: 
1) nunca te confíes de como se inicializan las cosas por defecto, dejar una variable o estructura de datos sin inicializar puede traerte muchos problemas a futuro, cuando un sistema escala crece, puede ser que al inicio funcione bien y luego mal, porque se inicializa de otra manera, me ha pasado te lo digo por experiencia propia, o que funcione bien en una maquina y mal en otra. te recomiendo que siempre inicialices todas tus variables!

Comment: @CetMartine 2) por como te han planteado el problema creo que quieren que te familiarices con recorrer arreglos, la solución que aceptaste no te ayuda a aprender como recorrer un arreglo o una lista, y ademas es código repetido fijate que las lineas son casi idénticas una abajo de otra, es una buena práctica de programación reemplazar el código repetido por un bucle como te indique con el for. te sugiero que lo resuelvas de esa forma para aprender

Answer (score 0):

en lenguaje C (en realidad en varios), la estructuras de tipo arreglo (array), que es constitución de datos en memoria, que pueden tener múltiples dimensiones, y se declaran de la siguiente forma general:

***tipo nombre[largo];***

por ejemplo, si quiero armar un arreglo de 5 posiciones, de tipo de de datos ***int***, lo defino como:

```
int arreglo[5];
```

para acceder a cada una de sus posiciones, se utiliza el indice (el indice indica la posicion en el arreglo), que en lenguaje C siempre comienza desde 0 (cero)

```
arreglo[0]   // Corresponde al primer elemento
arreglo[4]   // Corresponde al 5 elemento, que en este caso es el ultimo
```

este arreglo de elementos, se asigna de la misma forma y directamente si se tratase de una variable independiente.

Ejemplo:

```
int variable;
int arreglo[5];

variable=5;
arreglo[0] = 5; // estamos asignando un valor a la primera posición del arreglo
```

Ahora bien, para el caso de incrementos o decrementos, existe en C unos operadores definidos para tal efecto. Tenemos **++** que es un incrementador unario, o sea, le suma 1 a la variable, y **--** que es un decrementaor unario, o sea, le resta 1 a la variable.

Ejemplo:

```
int variable=3;
variable++;  // Ahora variable tendrá un valor de 4
```

que es lo mismo que hacer

```
int variable=3;
variable=variable+1; // Ahora variable tendrá un valor de 4
```

o

```
int variable=3;
variable+=1;   // Ahora variable tendrá un valor de 4
```

y eso lo puedes extrapolar a los elementos de un arreglo;

```
int arreglo[5];

arreglo[0]=3;
arreglo[0]++;  // Ahora arreglo[0] tendrá un valor de 4
```

espero te sirva esta simple explicación